# How to add -ObjC to the Linker file in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase

I am trying to add "-ObjC" to "Other Linker Flags" as part of the https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-quickstart.html tutorial.

Under Other Linker Flags it shows "Debug" and "Release", how/where would I put the "-ObjC">

[image: Edit: This is what I see]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to click to the right of Other Linker Flags(under build settings) and add it.  This image shows how it goes.

[image]

Instead of the test to the left though, you should be clicking on your main project.

Comment: I'm not on my mac atm so I can't double check, but are you in Build Settings with All and Combined checked, as opposed to levels? I think you might be in the wrong section or have a wrong option selected, I recall there being some other option for Other Linker Flags.  I can double check when I get home.  Worst case scenario you can add the flag to both debug and release and it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Click on the project then go to build settings and type linker flags in the search bar. You want to use the second field.

Edit: Also what I did instead of clicking the arrow to split it into debug and release I double clicked where the flags are shown and it brought up a pop-up to edit them.

[image]

Comment: You can put it in both. One is used for testing while the other will be used when you want to release your app.

Comment: I added an image to show how to get around the debug/release options